# Weird gcc error stray/missing terminating " character in C

Tags: c, gcc, string-literals

I get the following errors:

```
error: missing terminating " character
```

and

```
error: stray `\' in program
```

In this line of C code:

```
 system("sqlite3 -html /home/user/.rtcom-eventlogger/el.db \"SELECT service_id, event_type_id,free_text, remote_uid FROM Events WHERE remote_uid=\'%d\' ORDER BY start_time DESC;\" > lol.html", nr);
```

"nr" is a integer variable.

I have gone over this so many times but are totally stuck of finding a solution.

EDIT: The errors is the ouput while compiling with gcc if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Please paste the code above and below this line.

Comment: I don't think that this is the bug in question, but it appears that you are trying to pass printf style format/arguments to `system`, and it doesn't take them.  Well, it doesn't know what to do with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a double-quoted string in C, I don't think that `\'` has any meaning. It looks like your backslashing there is meant to protect the single quotes in the *shell*, which means they should be double-backslashed within the string: `remote_uid=\\'%d\\'`.

Comment: I want the system call to print out remote_uid='contents-of-nr-variable' in the shell I still get an error with \\'%d\\'

Comment: At least in C99 both `\'` and `'` can be used in string literals.

Comment: This is gcc 4.1 on an ARM system.

Comment: @DreamCodeR, but does it compile with the `'` double-escaped? If so, then I suggest that you printf your statement so that you can see what's actually being expanded.

Comment: @JS Bang:  printf("sqlite3 -html /home/user/.rtcom-eventlogger/el.db \"SELECT service_id, event_type_id,free_text, remote_uid FROM Events WHERE remote_uid='%d' ORDER BY start_time DESC;\" > lol.html", nr);

Gives me the same error. Also the same error when I compile with remote_uid=\\'%d\\'

Comment: I can compile the line you posted just fine. Is there something on the surrounding lines that you're not showing us?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't need to escape the single quotes inside the string (e.g. `\'` should just be `'`), but I'm not sure that that would cause the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, trying to do basically the same thing.

My problem was that I used WinZip to decompress the source.  After using 7z it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had an external define variable with escaped ", like this:

```
#define DEFINE \"string\"
```

It was transcluded into code like this:

```
cout << DEFINE; // source code

cout << \"string\"; // source code during compilation
```